# Is there any hook before save an order in database in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I want to remove some order item(s) from an order. Is there any way to remove order item before save the order ?
I have used the code. But did not work for me.

```
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $pID = $item['product_id'];
        $isSale = get_post_meta($pID,'is_sale_quote',true);
        if($isSale == 1)
        {
             wc_delete_order_item( absint( $pID ) );
        }

    }
    return $order_id;
}
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
```

Please let me know is there any wrong or is there ant better solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure call this functin **custom_process_order** .???

Comment: Check your database to see if the meta_key `is_sale_quote` does exists, depending on how you created it it may be called `_is_sale_quote`

Comment: I have checked it. the meta key exists in database. is there any hook like woocommerce_before_save_order ?

Comment: @papiya debnath Try this hook `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', custom_process_order );`

Comment: Perhaps the [`woocommerce_check_cart_items`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/9e41552342d07796d3ee5cefea76935288b65c6e/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L135) hook.